# Can a lambda return a reference to a capture?

Tags: c++, lambda, return-value

My program is crashing, due to what looks like some undefined behavior.  I believe I've narrowed it down to the following code (but it's tricky to tell, because when I try to create a minimal crashing example, it actually doesn't crash, as sometimes happens with UB).

Is the behavior of the following code undefined?

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

function<const function<void()> &()> defineFunction(function<void()> do_stuff) {
    return [do_stuff]() {
        return do_stuff;
    };
}

int main() {
    const function<void()> &do_stuff = defineFunction([]() {});
    do_stuff(); // undefined behavior?
}
```

I know that you can't return a reference to a local variable, however you can return a reference to a static local variable, or a global variable.  Here, `do_stuff` is part of the lambda's closure, so I assumed it would behave like a const static variable for purposes of returning a reference to it.  This does not appear to be the case, since in a larger program that contains this kind of code, the call to `do_stuff` fails.

Comment: No, captured variables are not static. They are regular non-static members of the unnamed class of the lambda.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Note that your snippet doesn't compile with clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46abc53265db763b).

Comment: BTW, Your lambda doesn't return reference, but value.

Comment: What's the error when you compile with clang?  It compiles just fine with clang 5.0.0 for me.

Comment: @Jarod42 do you mean the lambda has return type `function<void()>` unless `return [do_stuff]() {` is changed to `return [do_stuff]() -> const function<void()> & {`?

Comment: @jcarpenter: I linked the demo where you can see the error: *"no viable conversion from 'function<const function<void ()> &()>' to 'const function<void ()>'"*. For the second part, yes it is what I meant.